# Specified AJAX request not firing on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a CoffeeScript which GETs JSON data when the page loads, and should send a POST request when the element w/

```
data-behavior='notifications']
```

as an attribute is clicked. The whole script:

```
class Notifications
    constructor: ->
        @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")
        @setup() if @notifications.length > 0 

    setup: -> 
        $("[data-behavior='notifications-link']").on "click", @handleClick

        $.ajax(
            url: "/notifications.json"
            dataType: "JSON"
            method: "GET"
            success: @handleSuccess
        )
    handleClick: (e) =>
        $.ajax(
            url: "/notifications/mark_as_read"
            dataType: "JSON"
            method: "POST"
            success: ->
                $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text("")                
        )
    handleSuccess: (data) =>
       console.log(data) 
       items = $.map data, (notification) ->
            "<a class='dropdown-item' href='#{notification.url}'>#{notification.actor} #{notification.action} #{notification.notifiable.type}</a>"
       console.log(items)

        $("[data-behavior='notification-items']").html(items)
        $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(items.length)
    if items.length is 0
        $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text("")               

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', -> new Notifications)
```

Comment: which ajax is not firing?

Comment: The one responsible for the POST request

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an `NotificationsController` because this is where you head your `POST` to. So make sure your `mark_as_read` method responds to js format and that the script you mentioned is the view associated with that method(`mark_as_read.coffee.erb`)

Feel free to ask extra questions in comments unless my advice was not exactly  appropriate.

Comment: I do that using the respond_to method right? Doesn't work with AJAX 'the rails way.' I got it from a tut, here's the link https://gorails.com/episodes/in-app-navbar-notifications

Comment: The GET request goes thru properly on every page load. It's when I click on the element designated by that data-behavior='notifications', which is suppose to trigger the handleClick function responsible for the POST request is where my script fails

Comment: So it doesn't even make a request?

Comment: do you see this part of code(compailed to js obviously) on your page in Developer tools?

Comment: It's running the GET AJAX request and subsequently calling the handleSuccess function, but doesn't execute any javascript on the click event